# nested repeater control and item count of child repeater

Tags: c#, asp.net

[image: Here is my output]I have designed a employee data using nested Employee data.I have two table emp and dept .Table information
emp-empid(PK),empname,empjob,empsalary,deptid
dept-deptid(FK),deptname

I have shown the data in department wise.Parent repeater shows the department table and child repeater shows the emp details.And i want to count my total number of employee department wise as well as total salary.like wise in last i want to count grand total employee and grand total salary.But the problem I'm facing in counting the no of employee and salary department wise.here is my aspx.cs page .. If you are not getting me what's my problem .. then see the output I've attached with one screenshot

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
using System.Data;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using System.Configuration;

 public partial class RepeaterControlNested : System.Web.UI.Page
 {
    SqlConnection cn = null;
    SqlCommand cmd = null;
    SqlDataAdapter da = null;
    DataSet ds = null;
    int TotalEmployeeCount = 0;
    decimal TotalSalary = 0;
    int GrandTotalEmployeeCount = 0;
    decimal GrandTotalSalary = 0;
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
       cn = new      [![enter image description here][1]][1]SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["conStr"].ConnectionString);
    if (!Page.IsPostBack)
    {
        BindDept();
    }
}
void BindDept()
{
    da = new SqlDataAdapter("select * from dept", cn);
    ds = new DataSet();
    da.Fill(ds, "dept");
    deptRepeater.DataSource = ds.Tables["dept"];
    deptRepeater.DataBind();
}

protected void deptRepeater_ItemDataBound(object sender, RepeaterItemEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Item.ItemType == ListItemType.Item || e.Item.ItemType == ListItemType.AlternatingItem)
    {
        Repeater EmpRepeater = (Repeater)e.Item.FindControl("EmpRepeater");
        Label lblDeptId = (Label)e.Item.FindControl("lblDeptId");
        Label lblStatus = (Label)e.Item.FindControl("lblStatus");
        da = new SqlDataAdapter("select e.empid,e.empname,e.empjob,e.empsalary,d.deptname from emp e, dept d where e.deptid=d.deptid and d.deptid=" + lblDeptId.Text, cn);
        ds = new DataSet();
        da.Fill(ds, "emp");
        if (ds.Tables["emp"].Rows.Count > 0)
        {
            EmpRepeater.DataSource = ds.Tables["emp"];
            EmpRepeater.DataBind();
        }
        else
        {
            lblStatus.Text = "no data available";
        }

    }
    if (e.Item.ItemType == ListItemType.Footer)
    {
        Label lblGrandTotalEmp = (Label)e.Item.FindControl("lblGrandTotalEmp");
        lblGrandTotalEmp.Text = GrandTotalEmployeeCount.ToString();
        Label lblGrandTotalSalary = (Label)e.Item.FindControl("lblGrandTotalSalary");
        lblGrandTotalSalary.Text = GrandTotalSalary.ToString("c");
    }
    TotalSalary = 0;
    TotalEmployeeCount = 0;
}

protected void EmpRepeater_ItemDataBound(object sender, RepeaterItemEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Item.ItemType == ListItemType.Item || e.Item.ItemType == ListItemType.Item)
    {
        Label lblEmpSalary = (Label)e.Item.FindControl("lblEmpSalary");
        Label lblGrandTotalSalary = (Label)e.Item.FindControl("lblGrandTotalSalary");
        if (lblEmpSalary != null)
        {

            TotalSalary += decimal.Parse(lblEmpSalary.Text);
            TotalEmployeeCount += 1;
            GrandTotalEmployeeCount += 1;
            GrandTotalSalary = GrandTotalSalary + decimal.Parse(lblEmpSalary.Text);
        }
    }
    if (e.Item.ItemType == ListItemType.Footer)
    {
        Label lblTotalEmp = (Label)e.Item.FindControl("lblTotalEmp");
        lblTotalEmp.Text = TotalEmployeeCount.ToString();
        Label lblTotalSalary = (Label)e.Item.FindControl("lblTotalSalary");
        lblTotalSalary.Text = TotalSalary.ToString("c");

    }
}
```

}

here is my design page -

```
   <%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true"    CodeFile="RepeaterControlNested.aspx.cs" Inherits="RepeaterControlNested" %>

     <!DOCTYPE html>

    <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
  <head runat="server">
  <title></title>
 </head>
   <body>
     <form id="form1" runat="server">
   <div>
   <table border="1" style="background-color:blue;color:white" width="100%">
   <tr>
       <th align="center">Employee Data</th>
   </tr>
</table>
</div>
    <div>
      <asp:Repeater ID="deptRepeater" runat="server" OnItemDataBound="deptRepeater_ItemDataBound">
          <ItemTemplate>
              <table width="100%">
                  <tr style="background-color:#2bb9d9;color:white">
                      <td align="left">
                          Dept Name : <%#Eval("deptname") %>
                          <asp:Label ID="lblDeptId" runat="server"  Style="display:none" Text='<%#Eval("deptid") %>'></asp:Label>
                      </td>
                  </tr>
              </table>
             <asp:Repeater ID="EmpRepeater" runat="server" OnItemDataBound="EmpRepeater_ItemDataBound">
                <HeaderTemplate>
                    <table width="100%">
                        <tr style="background-color:yellow;color:green">
                            <td width="20%">Emp Id</td>
                            <td width="20%">Emp Name</td>
                            <td width="20%">Emp Job</td>
                            <td width="20%">Emp Salary</td>
                            <td width="20%">Dept Name</td>
                        </tr>
                    </table>
                </HeaderTemplate>
                 <ItemTemplate>
                     <table width="100%">
                         <tr>
                             <td width="20%">
                                 <%#Eval("empid") %>
                             </td>
                             <td width="20%">
                                 <%#Eval("empname") %>
                             </td>
                             <td width="20%">
                                 <%#Eval("empjob") %>
                             </td>
                             <td width="20%">
                                 <asp:Label ID="lblEmpSalary" runat="server" Text='<%#Eval("empsalary") %>'></asp:Label>
                             </td>
                             <td width="20%">
                                 <%#Eval("deptname") %>
                             </td>
                         </tr>
                     </table>
                 </ItemTemplate>

                 <FooterTemplate>
                     <table width="100%">
                         <tr style="background-color:yellow;color:green">
                             <th width="40%" colspan="2" align="left">
                                 Total no of employee:
                                 <asp:Label ID="lblTotalEmp" runat="server"></asp:Label>
                             </th>
                             <th width="20%" align="right">
                                 Total Salary:
                             </th>
                            <th width="40%" colspan="2" align="left"> 
                                <asp:Label ID="lblTotalSalary" runat="server"></asp:Label>
                            </th>
                         </tr>
                     </table>
                 </FooterTemplate>
             </asp:Repeater>
              <asp:Label ID="lblStatus" runat="server" BackColor="Red" ForeColor="White"></asp:Label>
          </ItemTemplate>
          <FooterTemplate>
              <table width="100%">
                  <tr style="background-color:yellow;color:green">
                       <th width="40%" colspan="2" align="left">
                                 GrandTotal of employee:
                                 <asp:Label ID="lblGrandTotalEmp" runat="server"></asp:Label>
                             </th>
                             <th width="20%" align="right">
                                Grand Total Salary:
                             </th>
                            <th width="40%" colspan="2" align="left"> 
                                <asp:Label ID="lblGrandTotalSalary" runat="server"></asp:Label>
                            </th>
                  </tr>
              </table>
          </FooterTemplate>
      </asp:Repeater>
    </div>
</form>
```

```
enter code here
```

Comment: You shouldn't be executing a SQL query once for the outer repeater and then *executing another query for every single row*.  Execute one query that gets all of the data (via a JOIN) that you need, and then bind all of that to your repeater all at once.  Once you do that, your current problem will just become moot, as you'll already have the count of the inner items when you're setting the other fields of that row in the outer repeater.

Comment: I think you simply have a bug in the employee's repeater and you're missing AlternateItem.

Comment: @hivo I didn't attached any alternatingitem here.. see I have updated my question and also added aspx page too

Comment: @Servy well I don't think it's an issue..Every time an itembound event is fired the dataset get empty ..So no point to take a single query using join

Comment: @chikun The only reason there wouldn't be a point is if you never have more than one row in your result set.  If you have more than one row, you're doing *way* more work than you should be, both on your web server, and in your database, while *also* making it way harder for you to do what you want.  There's just no good reason to be doing this at all.  You should almost never be using the item data bound event; it's *usually* the wrong tool for any given job.

Answer (score 0):

only mistake I was doing is in this statement

```
     if (e.Item.ItemType == ListItemType.Item || e.Item.ItemType ==  ListItemType.Item)
```

instead 
i should write

```
 if (e.Item.ItemType == ListItemType.Item || e.Item.ItemType == ListItemType.AlternatingItem)
```

now it is working